# NullPointerException when run gradle htmlDependencyReport

Tags: gradle, nullpointerexception, gradle-plugin

I'm learning gradle. So I created a very simple project and when I run `gradle htmlDependencyReport` command  I get `NullPointerException`. Gradle version is 2.10
My `build.gradle` file looks like this:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group 'info.garagesalesapp'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
    compile 'com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1.1'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}

apply plugin: 'project-report'
```

Stacktrace:

```
Notebook-PC:~/workspace/java-project$ gradle htmlDependencyReport --stacktrace
:htmlDependencyReport FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':htmlDependencyReport'.
> Could not write to file '/home/iurii/workspace/java-project/build/reports/project/dependencies/root.html'.

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':htmlDependencyReport'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:203)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:185)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:66)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:50)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:25)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:110)
        at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$4.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:154)
        at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:52)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:151)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.access$200(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:32)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:99)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:93)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:62)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:93)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:82)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:94)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:78)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:48)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:43)
        at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:170)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:237)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:210)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:206)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
        at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:54)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: Could not write to file '/home/iurii/workspace/java-project/build/reports/project/dependencies/root.html'.
        at org.gradle.internal.IoActions$TextFileWriterIoAction.execute(IoActions.java:115)
        at org.gradle.internal.IoActions$TextFileWriterIoAction.execute(IoActions.java:91)
        at org.gradle.internal.IoActions.writeTextFile(IoActions.java:38)
        at org.gradle.reporting.HtmlReportRenderer$DefaultHtmlReportContext.renderRawHtmlPage(HtmlReportRenderer.java:130)
        at org.gradle.reporting.HtmlReportBuilder$renderRawHtmlPage.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.api.reporting.dependencies.internal.HtmlDependencyReporter$1.render(HtmlDependencyReporter.groovy:66)
        at org.gradle.api.reporting.dependencies.internal.HtmlDependencyReporter$1.render(HtmlDependencyReporter.groovy)
        at org.gradle.reporting.HtmlReportRenderer.render(HtmlReportRenderer.java:42)
        at org.gradle.reporting.HtmlReportRenderer$render.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.api.reporting.dependencies.internal.HtmlDependencyReporter.render(HtmlDependencyReporter.groovy:55)
        at org.gradle.api.reporting.dependencies.HtmlDependencyReportTask.generate(HtmlDependencyReportTask.java:104)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:75)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:227)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:220)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:209)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:585)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:568)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
        ... 57 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.gradle.reporting.HtmlReportRenderer$DefaultHtmlReportContext.addResource(HtmlReportRenderer.java:97)
        at org.gradle.reporting.HtmlReportRenderer$DefaultHtmlReportContext$DefaultHtmlPageBuilder.requireResource(HtmlReportRenderer.java:162)
        at org.gradle.api.reporting.dependencies.internal.ProjectPageRenderer.render(ProjectPageRenderer.java:41)
        at org.gradle.api.reporting.dependencies.internal.ProjectPageRenderer.render(ProjectPageRenderer.java:30)
        at org.gradle.reporting.HtmlReportRenderer$DefaultHtmlReportContext$2.doExecute(HtmlReportRenderer.java:133)
        at org.gradle.reporting.HtmlReportRenderer$DefaultHtmlReportContext$2.doExecute(HtmlReportRenderer.java:130)
        at org.gradle.internal.ErroringAction.execute(ErroringAction.java:35)
        at org.gradle.internal.IoActions$TextFileWriterIoAction.execute(IoActions.java:110)
        ... 75 more


BUILD FAILED
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

updated gradle to the latest version (4.7) and everything works.

Comment: Please accept your answer, otherwise your question appears in search results with no accepted answers.

Comment: @PeterLedbrook I've tried already but I cannot accept my own answer in 2 days. That's what the stackoverflow says.

Answer (score 0):

Same here

```
gradle wrapper --gradle-version 5.6.3
./gradlew htmlDependencyReport
```

Works like a charm!